# Search in PyCharm interactive console command history

Tags: python, pycharm, console

PyCharm keeps a command history for it's interactive Python console.

Is there a way to access this history with some sort of search instead of just browsing the entries with the arrow keys in the interactive console window?

My environment: PyCharm 2.7 EAP (124.138) on MacOS X 10.8.2.

Comment: As a suggestion would you accept the 2nd answer? It's up-to-date, the feature exists from 2014.

Comment: "As a suggestion would you accept the 2nd answer? It's up-to-date, the feature exists from 2014"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of PyCharm 3.1, while in the console, press ⌥⌘e, the "Browse History" window will come up, start typing to search for specific commands

Comment: Does anyone know the windows or linux keyboard shortcut here?

Comment: In Windows, it appears to be Ctrl + Alt + E

Comment: gotta love those mac symbols... just press escalator cloverleaf! Not even most mac people seem to be able to interpret the mysterious escalator symbol...

Answer (score 13):

Not available yet, please vote for the related feature requests:

- [PY-7922](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7922) In console, search history by typing prefix and pressing the "up" key
- [PY-5011](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5011) Ctrl+R in console should invoke history search like in bash

Comment: Just to follow-up. This is now available in the PyCharm Python Console. The feature is called _Browse History_. (I use PyCharm 3.1 EAP.)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this still doesn't seem to be working. I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4. Ctrl+E nor Ctrl+R work.

Comment: Ctrl-R doesn't work if Editor uses Vim mode.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays, there is **"Browse Console History"** button located to the left of python console. It works on all OS where PyCharm works.

In Windows and Linux there is **Ctrl+Alt+E** which does exectly the same, but it may not work on Linux if it is overriden by system hotkey Alt.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Windows you can use Ctrl Alt e