# How to see the full previous command in Pycharm Python console using a shortcut

Tags: python, console, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering how I could see the history in the Pycharm Python console using a shortcut. I can see the history using the upper arrow key, but If I want to go further back in history I have to go to each individual line if more lines are ran at the time. Is it possible that each time I press a button the full previous commands that are ran are shown?

I don't want to search in history, I want to go back in history similar using arrow up key but each time I enter arrow up I want to see the previous full code that was ran.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in PyCharm interactive console command history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842774/search-in-pycharm-interactive-console-command-history)

Comment: See the edit, this is not the answer I was looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences -> Appereance & Behaviour -> Keymap. You can search for "Browse Console History" and add a keyboard shortcut with right click -> Add Keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, that almost does the job but now I have to press minimal three times a button to run a full command in the history CTRL ALT E + Arrow Up + Enter + Enter, I was hoping for a shortcut that combines the first three shortcuts, which is the case in for example Spyder if I press arrow up

Comment: You can achieve this by binding a keyboard shortcut to a macro. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html)